# Where can I find a good Silverlight 4 WCF duplex tutorial?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, duplex

I'm interested in seeing a good example of a duplex service that a Silverlight 4 application connects to, is there one out there? I'm willing to get a book if it's located in it.

I went though the MSDN one located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and didn't follow it very well, or even get it working.

Comment: One of the rear examples that I managed to work: http://cid-8890f90042412611.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/ForAll/Chat.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 best examples I've found:

http://www.42spikes.com/post/Using-Silverlight-4-and-NetTCP-Duplex-Callbacks.aspx

http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/pubsub-sample-with-wcf-nettcp-protocol.html

some good info --
http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/wcf-nettcp-protocol-in-silverlight-4.html

Hope that helps --

Chad